# SSL Certificate on HSTS domains

Tags: ssl, apache2, certbot, hsts

I have a new domain in the `.dev` TLD, which is forced HSTS as far as I understood, so I can't access it through HTTP but HTTPS only.

Im trying to setup the SSL certificate like I did 100 times before using certbot on ubuntu/apache2.

Now my problem is that when the certbot tries to authenticate, it doesn't work because the acme-challenge tries to access the file in .well-known through HTTP, which doesn't work with HSTS domains.

How do you usually deal with that, I couldn't find anything useful so far.

Error message from certbot:

```
Failed authorization procedure. example.dev (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.dev/.well-known/acme-challenge/t6qvuntJAoDTAwoMnjQnA5R4vZ-IdWptb_yakexutp4 [2001:8d8:100f:f000::259]: 204

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.dev
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.dev/.well-known/acme-challenge/t6qvuntJAoDTAwoMnjQnA5R4vZ-IdWptb_yakexutp4
   [2001:8d8:100f:f000::259]: 204

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Comment: "through HTTP, which doesn't work with HSTS domains." That is not right. HSTS just forces browsers to use the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP. It absolutely does not forbid you to run a webservice on port 80 for HTTP and have a CA using it. Alternatively you can also validate with DNS records instead of HTTP.

Comment: The error you quote shows that something replied for the HTTP request, but replied with HTTP error code `204`. Look at your webserver logfiles.

Comment: I havent been able to solve this problem, but I just didn't use certbot and added the SSL manually.